What's the geometric meaning of $|n-z_1-z_2-\cdots-z_n|\ge|1-z_1z_2\cdots z_n|$ with $|z_k|\leq1,1\leq k\leq n$?
In AoPS, I encounter an interesting inequality which says that: if $z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_n\in \mathbb{C}$ and $|z_k|\le 1$ then :
$$|n-z_1-z_2-\cdots-z_n|\ge|1-z_1z_2\cdots z_n|.\tag{*}$$
For the proof, we can refer Proof.
The proof refered above is based on induction.
I want to know if the inequality $(*)$ has a geometric meaning or some background which can help us to get a concise proof.  Even for the  case $n=2$, $(*)$ becomes
$$|2-z_1-z_2|\ge|1-z_1z_2|,\quad |z_1|\leq1,|z_2|\leq1.$$
Any comments and other proofs will welcome.
Update:

For geometric meaning, I mean in the following sense:

For exmple, when $z_k=x_k\in\mathbb R$ and $-1\leq x_k\leq1$ for $1\leq k\leq n$, the inequality becomes
$$n-x_1-x_2-\cdots-x_n \geq 1-x_1x_2\cdots x_n,$$
this is equivalent to
$$(x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1}-1)x_n+(n-1-x_1-x_2-\cdots-x_{n-1})\geq0.$$
If we fix $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1}$ and let $x=x_n\in[-1,1]$ be a variable,
then the left side is linear function
$$f(x)=kx+b,\quad k=x_1x_2\cdots x_{n-1}-1,b=n-1-x_1-x_2-\cdots-x_{n-1}.$$
It is enough to check
$$f(-1)\geq0,\quad f(1)\geq0.$$

I'd start by $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$ and
$$Z_k =  r_k\omega^{k-1}$$
$$|r_k|\leq 1$$
And use triangle inequalities. I started doing it this way because you see the geometric meaning of the operation where all the roots of unity cancel out in:
$$|n-\sum_{k=1}^{n} Z_k|\leq n+ \left|\omega^{\frac{n}{2}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} Z_k\right|$$
I'll try to post a full solution starting from here if you are interested.

@ phionez
Thank you! Looking forward to your answer！

I think I underestimated the difficulty here. Your question got my interest because it looks similar to another cool fact being that for $Z_k$ being complex numbers forming an n-gon $Z_k = c + r\omega^{k-1}$ being r and c complex constants you have that this holds:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} Z_kZ_{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} Z^2_k=nc^2$$

A little comment on "What is the gepmetric meaning of..." : most algebraic equalities or inequalities are devoided of a geometric interpretation...

@
Jean Marie
Thank you for your comment. I have added a "geometric interpretation" for real variable!
